# I want a single ListView to have 2 different columns 'label' and 'values' in android studio 3.4.2 using Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, arraylist

I have climate for certain city which I want to display in a ListView. If I add both of them to a single string and then add them into ListView using array adapter, then I am losing indentation.

E.g.

Temperature:20deg C

Sunrise:06:39

Time Zone:GMT+05:30

etc.

First ArrayList is labels and second ArrayList is detWeatherInfo.

I have tried StringBuilder builder. 
builder.append(" "); until the labels string is of certain length (say 20) but due to different space occupied by various alphabets it is not working either.

Temperature             :20deg C

Sunrise              :06:39

Time Zone           :GMT+05:30

(I wanted all ":" below one another and at some space after label strings are finished)

Hence I have tried 2 different Listviews. But when number of rows exceed the screensize, two ListViews scroll individually and hence I lose the value from corresponding label name.

I also tried,

```
ArrayList <Hashmap<String,String>> combined = new ArrayList 
<Hashmap<String,String>>();

Hashmap <String,String> map = new Hashmap <String,String>();
```

then

```
for(int i=0;i<detWeatherInfo.size();i++)
{
      map.put(labels.get(i),detWeatherInfo.get(i));
}

combined.add(map);

arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,combined);
```

but this arrayAdapter is not accepting the value of the ArrayList combined.

Current code:

```
      ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,labels);

                    listView1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        }
                    });

                    arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,detWeatherInfo);

                    listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        }
                    });
```

I want output to be in 2 different columns in a single ListView.

Comment: learn RecyclerView immediately year is 2019

Comment: Why are you using such a old method?

Comment: It was a part of the tutorial. Can you suggest any link for recycler view for beginners?

Comment: It was a part of the tutorial. Can you suggest any link for recycler view for beginners?